# update or merge arrayadapter with new data - button more

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I need to add in the ListView existing more data I get from a database, however, using a "more" button without start or refresh activity.

I suggested this way, using adapter.AddAll (NewAdapter), but it only displays the address (I think that's it) line in the list, as you can see in the image on the line added after clicking more as if he had not identified the xml field. But the adapter is the same, to create a new listview only with the new Adpter appears correctly.

[image]

Any suggestion?

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<RssItem> result) {
        progressBar.dismiss();

        // Get a ListView from main view
        ListView itcItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMainView);

        if (Integer.parseInt(limit) < 1) {
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RssItem>(local, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
            itcItems.setAdapter(adapter);
            itcItems.setOnItemClickListener(new ListListener(result, local));

        } else {

            Nadapter = new ArrayAdapter<RssItem>(local, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);

            if (Nadapter.getCount() == 0){
                final Button btMais = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btMais);
                btMais.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Don't more data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                adapter.addAll(Nadapter);
                itcItems.setAdapter(adapter);
                itcItems.setOnItemClickListener(new ListListener(result, local));
            }
        }
    }
```

End code and running with help Shadab:

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<RssItem> result) {
        progressBar.dismiss();

        // Get a ListView from main view
        ListView itcItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMainView);

        if (Integer.parseInt(limit) < 1) {
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RssItem>(local, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
            itcItems.setAdapter(adapter);
            itcItems.setOnItemClickListener(new ListListener(result, local));

        } else {

            Nadapter = new ArrayAdapter<RssItem>(local, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);

            if (Nadapter.getCount() == 0){
                final Button btMais = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btMais);
                btMais.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Don't more data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                adapter.addAll(result);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want to add some new data to your adapter, you have to "notify it" using **notifyDataSetChanged()** (It adds new data and refresh listview) hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a new adapter and merge but instead you need to set the new data in your already existing adapter and refresh it using `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

```
 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<RssItem> result) {
            progressBar.dismiss();

            // Get a ListView from main view
            ListView itcItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMainView);

            if (Integer.parseInt(limit) < 1) {
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RssItem>(local, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
                itcItems.setAdapter(adapter);
                itcItems.setOnItemClickListener(new ListListener(result, local));

            } else {



                if (Nadapter.getCount() == 0){
                    final Button btMais = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btMais);
                    btMais.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Don't more data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                  //Whatever your initial list was add the new data in that list
                    oldList.addAll(result);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I confess that I understand wrong as it treats the data in ArrayAdapter until had tried something similar, but using setAdapter again. Now is working the way you indicated, except that kept the (new adapter -Nadapter) Thanks Shadab.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the items on the adapter not a new adapter.

Reference: [ArrayAdaper documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html).